# Zero results on first page when ignoring topics

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, question-lists, pagination

If I view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers I come across a few questions with different tags. If I choose to ignore these tags and refresh the page, I get zero results. It's not until I go to page 2 or even 3 that I get results.

Why does this happen? Why doesn't it just bump the other results to the first page based on my ignored tags?

Comment: Annoying isn't it? The site doesn't really filter out results, it makes them invisible. But they're still there in the search results, not visible. It happens on meta too, I don't really care about documentation topics so I filtered the tags out and was left with "pages" of at most one meta question.

Comment: Yeh, I get that they are actually loaded in, then hidden but that doesn't make logical sense to me

Comment: Very much agreed, but I don't think this is a bug. I'm pretty sure this has to do with caching and performance.

Comment: It gets a bit ridiculous when I have a lot of ignored tags. Some times I have to go to page 5 just to see one result. Going to pages > 5 results in only one or 2 results per page. I ignore any tag that I come across and have no interest (currently around 100 ignored)